# Load different css/js for different views in laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

I am new to laravel. I use laravel 5.6 . I want to use Summernote WYSIWYG editor in only one page(view). Summernote need a css and a js file. I want to load these files only in this view. How do i do that?
Here is how I tried to do that.
 **master.blade.php** file.

```
<html>

    @include('header')

    <body>

        @yield('content')

        @include('footer')

    </body>
</html>
```

**editor.blade.php** file

```
@extends('master')

    @section('content')
        --- Summernote editor goes here---
    @endsection

    @section('imports')
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- include summernote css/js-->
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.summernote').summernote();
        });
    </script>
    @endsection
```

**header.blade.php**

```
<head>
    --- other css and file links ---

    @yield('imports')
</head>
```

As you can see editor.blade.php file extends the master.blade file. And in master file I included the header.blade file which hold all of css links. So I yielded the Summernote js/css in header.blade file. But when it loaded to browser, the yielded content in header.blade file are at the beginning of the `<body>` tag(which should be in side the `<head>` tag).
I could just add those files in headr.blade.php file directly. But I wonder if there's a way to do it in this way.

Comment: Could you post the actual code for: `---- Summernote css and js file links here ---`

Comment: updated the post @ChrisHappy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do this in this way, you don't use the include() blade in the master.blade since it will call to all pages regardless, just yield then in the other page just inject to that yielded section.

master.blade.js

```
<html>

    @yield('header')

    <body>

        @yield('content')

        @yield('footer')

    </body>
</html>
```

header.blade.php

```
 @extends('master')

    @section('header')
            --- CSS here ---
    @endsection

    @section('content')
        --- content here ---
    @endsection

    @section('footer')
        --- scripts here ---
    @endsection
```

Comment: Yeah. That is a really good way to do it. Do you have any idea, why my method is not woking here. Can’t we use yield in included files?

Comment: as you can see in your code, you have extended "master.blade" in your "editor.blade" which also contains the code that you are yielding (imports) This means all contents will go to the yielded content, which is inside the body.

Comment: Oh right. You mean, we can yield content in only one file. Right?

Comment: you can yield to many file, but you can't include to extended file that you yielded.

Comment: for more details about include https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views

Comment: Thank you so much!